# Sphinx / autodoc: how to cross-link to a function documented on another page

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, read-the-docs, autodoc

I am building a documentation of my Python package using Sphinx.

I have a `API.rst` file, in which I list my functions as follows: `.. autofunction:: mymodule.foo.bar1`

For the different functions that are autodocumented form this page, I can put for instance:

```
:func:`foo1`
```

in the docstring of `foo2()` and it will create a link to the first function.

However, if I have a second file `API2.rst`, in which I autodoc some other functions, the same syntax doesn't seem to find the links across different pages. Even the `See Also` functions are not linked.

Is there a way to specify and to link different functions across pages? Thanks

#### Example

- The repo's documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/neuropsychology/NeuroKit/tree/website-overhaul/docs_wip)
- For instance, in the docstring of [this function](https://neuropsychology.github.io/NeuroKit/functions/functions_hrv.html), under the parameter `peaks`, I am trying to link to another function called `ecg_peaks()` which is documented [here](https://neuropsychology.github.io/NeuroKit/functions/functions_ecg.html#ecg-peaks)

Comment: Do you see any warnings or errors when building the docs?

Comment: No, none, unfortunately :/

Comment: please provide a repository as an example where we can reproduce this behavior

Comment: It is on the website-overhaul branch, the docstring is [here](https://github.com/neuropsychology/NeuroKit/blob/c56bf4bd42d89dbdabf62df6d2232f1fb091a1c8/neurokit2/hrv/hrv.py#L27-L30). Thanks!

Comment: Does it work if you simply prefix the function name in the cross-reference with a dot (`.ecg_peaks`)? See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#cross-referencing-python-objects

Comment: To get warnings about missing cross-reference targets, set `nitpicky = True` in conf.py. See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html?highlight=nitpicky#confval-nitpicky

Comment: I tried adding dots (https://github.com/neuropsychology/NeuroKit/blob/website-overhaul/neurokit2/hrv/hrv.py#L29) but no changes. Setting `nitpicky=True` simply gave ` WARNING: py:func reference target not found: ecg_peaks`

Comment: "No changes"? - On https://neuropsychology.github.io/NeuroKit/functions/functions_hrv.html, the links to `ecg_peaks()` and `ecg_process()` work now.

Comment: Wow indeed, I checked the wrong version! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To sum up what other commenters found, when Sphinx resolve Python cross-references, it can find the cross-reference targets in several ways. Let's get an example.

Say you have the following project structure

```
my-project/
├── docs/            # Where your docs, and conf.py are
└── my_project/      # where the Python code is, importable from Sphinx
    ├── __init__.py  # empty file
    ├── foobar.py    # defines the foo_func and bar_func functions
    └── baz.py       # defines the Baz class which as a baz_meth method
```

- **Absolute qualified name**: Anywhere in your documentation you
  should be able to make a fully qualified reference, like so

  ```
  See the :func:`my_project.foobar.foo_func` function
  ```
- **Relative name**: In a given module, you can use the Python
  object name directly.  For instance, from within the
  from foobar.py file:

  ```
  See the :func:`foo_func` function.
  ```
- **Relaxed qualified name**: When referencing a python object
  you can use the `.` character to extend the search space for your target. As an example, from foobar.py file:

  ```
  See the :func:`.foo_func` function.
  ```

  Also, from the class docstring of Baz, in baz.py:

  ```
  See the :meth:`.baz_meth` method.
  ```

  The risk with the relaxed method is that Sphinx will link
  to the first thing it finds, which may of may not be the target
  you expected.

Finally, to help prevent these issues go public, use the [nitpick option](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-nitpicky)

Here is what [Sphinx documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#cross-referencing-python-objects) says on this topic

> The name enclosed in this markup can include a module name and/or a
> class name. For example, :py:func:`filter` could refer to a function
> named filter in the current module, or the built-in function of that
> name. In contrast, :py:func:`foo.filter` clearly refers to the filter
> function in the foo module.
>
> Normally, names in these roles are searched first without any further
> qualification, then with the current module name prepended, then with
> the current module and class name (if any) prepended. If you prefix
> the name with a dot, this order is reversed. For example, in the
> documentation of Python’s codecs module, :py:func:`open` always refers
> to the built-in function, while :py:func:`.open` refers to
> codecs.open().
>
> A similar heuristic is used to determine whether the name is an
> attribute of the currently documented class.
>
> Also, if the name is prefixed with a dot, and no exact match is found,
> the target is taken as a suffix and all object names with that suffix
> are searched. For example, :py:meth:`.TarFile.close` references the
> tarfile.TarFile.close() function, even if the current module is not
> tarfile. Since this can get ambiguous, if there is more than one
> possible match, you will get a warning from Sphinx.
>
> Note that you can combine the ~ and . prefixes:
> :py:meth:`~.TarFile.close` will reference the tarfile.TarFile.close()
> method, but the visible link caption will only be close().

Comment: I could only get this to work with ```:func:`.foo_func` ``` and not ```:func:`project.foo_func` ```

Comment: @sam this can probably be fixed making sure your pythonpath is properly set in your conf.py